# Can not find Data Retention under Usage and Estimated Cost

Tags: azure-application-insights

I am following this documentation. However, the Data Retention option is not visible in Azure Portal.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/pricing#change-the-data-retention-period

Comment: Hi Zaali, this feature is online now. If the answer is helpful, could you please help mark it as answer as per this [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top). Thanks. It would be helpful for others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

the data retention feature is online now.

---

This feature(Data Retention option) was temporarily removed because the product team is working on fixing a possible issue. And it will be brought back a few days later. More details is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/pricing#change-the-data-retention-period), in Note section.

A screenshot of the Note section:

[image]